# Celery fails to accept tasks

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I'm adding a backend for Celery results, and I'm having an issue where I send tasks, and some are accepted while others aren't.

Tasks that are and aren't executed both show this log output:

```
[2014-06-09 15:50:59,091: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.multithread_device_listing[e3ae6d12-ad4b-4114-9383-5802c91541f2]
```

Ones that ARE executed then show this output:

```
[2014-06-09 15:50:59,093: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: tasks.multithread_device_listing[e3ae6d12-ad4b-4114-9383-5802c91541f2] pid:2810
```

While tasks that AREN'T executed never arrive at the above line.

How I send tasks:

```
from celery import group
from time import sleep


signatures = []
signature = some_method_with_task_decorator.subtask()
signatures.append(signature)
signature = some_other_method_with_task_decorator.subtask()
signatures.append(signature)
job = group(signatures)
result = job.apply_async()
while not result.ready():
    sleep(60)
```

My celery config from having it report it is:

```
    software -> celery:3.1.11 (Cipater) kombu:3.0.18 py:2.7.5
                billiard:3.3.0.17 py-amqp:1.4.5
    platform -> system:Darwin arch:64bit imp:CPython
    loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    settings -> transport:amqp results:amqp://username:pass@localhost:5672/automated_reports

    CELERY_QUEUES:
        (<unbound Queue automated_reports -> <unbound Exchange default(direct)> -> automated_reports>,)
    CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY: '********'
    CELERY_INCLUDE:
        ('celery.app.builtins',
     'automated_reports.queue.tasks',
     'automated_reports.queue.subtasks')
    CELERY_IMPORTS:
        ('automated_reports.queue.tasks', 'automated_reports.queue.subtasks')
    CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT: True
    CELERY_ROUTES: {
        'automated_reports.queue.tasks.run_device_info_report': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'},
        'uploader.queue.subtasks.multithread_device_listing': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'},
        'uploader.queue.subtasks.multithread_individual_device': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'},
        'uploader.queue.tasks.multithread_device_listing': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'},
        'uploader.queue.tasks.multithread_individual_device': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'}}
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE: 'automated_reports'
    BROKER_URL: 'amqp://username:********@localhost:5672/automated_reports'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'amqp://username:pass@localhost:5672/automated_reports'
```

My startup command is:

```
~/Documents/Development/automated_reports/bin/celery worker --loglevel=DEBUG --autoreload -A automated_reports.queue.tasks -Q automated_reports -B --schedule=~/Documents/Development/automated_reports/log/celerybeat --autoscale=10,3
```

Also, when I stop celery, it pulls tasks out of my queue that were never accepted. Then when I restart, it accepts them and executes them.

Any help with this behavior is much appreciated. I'm certain it has something to do with my backend configuration, but I'm having difficulty isolating the issue or its correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this.

I noticed that the 'inqueue' seemed to be properly receiving tasks in some cases, but not others. When I searched the Celery docs, I found this note: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html?highlight=inqueue#caveats

I was executing the subtasks from within a long-running task, so this sounded very much like the behavior I was seeing. Also, I'm on the version mentioned, whereas on previous versions I hadn't had this problem with the same config.

I added the -Ofair parameter to starting the worker, and it immediately resolved the issue.